# How can you manipulate large files faster in python?

Tags: python, bigdata

I have to loop through 30GB of files (there is 30 of them) and 500mb is taking around 15mins.
How can I optimize the performance knowing that I am looping through each line by line?

Python

```
import json
import os

def file_subreddit_comments(rfname,wfname):
    with open(rfname, 'r', encoding="utf8") as rf:
        with open(wfname, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as wf:
            for i, l in enumerate(rf):
                d = json.loads(l)
                link_id = d["link_id"]
                for lsi in list_submission_id:
                    constructed_link_id = "t3_" + lsi
                    if link_id == constructed_link_id:
                        wf.write(l)                    

defaultFilePath = r'D:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Reddit Data\Run Comments\\'
directory = os.fsencode(defaultFilePath)

list_submission_id = []
submission_id_file = r'D:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Reddit Data\Manipulated Data-09-03-19-Final\UniqueIDSubmissionsList-09-03-2019.txt'
with open(submission_id_file, "r", encoding="utf8") as sif:
    for i, l in enumerate(sif):
        list_submission_id.append(l.rstrip())

for file in os.listdir(directory):
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     comment_path_read = defaultFilePath + filename
     comment_path_save = defaultFilePath + filename + "_ext_com.txt"
     file_subreddit_comments(comment_path_read,comment_path_save)     
     print(filename)
```

The `submission_id_file` is a list that has around 1000 keywords in it and it needs to verify each if the value of `constructured_link_id` is within the list.

Comment: You might want to take a look at parallel processing in python to be able to parse several files at the same time and take advantage of all your CPUs.

Comment: I was able to do the multiprocessing version of the above code. It is taking 12 files at once. Thank you, it will surely help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreading and Multiprocessing might be a solution as proposed by Thom above. Well, at least it reduced the length of time performing my tasks. 12 cores = 12 files manipulated simultaneously.

Comment: multithread if you need interaction of these sub-batches; multiprocessing if u dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on a spinning platter hard drive you might be having issues with seek time.  Try writing all your data into an in memory object then dumping it all into a file at once at the end.

I can't be 100% sure this is the problem though, its just a theory.  Easy to try though.

EDIT: just spotted another big speedup.

make list_submission_id a set instead

```
list_submission_id = set()
list_submission_id.add("t3_" + l.rstrip())
```

Then check for membership using:

```
link_id = d["link_id"]
if link_id in list_submission_id :
    wf.write(l)
```

Unlike my other suggestion, this definitely WILL speed things up alot.